# Steering wheel transform using WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, lego-mindstorms

I'm a rank amateur when it comes to WPF and I'm working on building a UI with my boy for his Lego Mindstorms robot.

He's asked me to put a steering wheel in place of directional buttons and while I can do that, including the rotation transform, I don't know how to have that transform move on a mouse down / drag event, relative to the direction of the drag.

The XAML I have so far is this:

```
    <Image x:Name="steering" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="146" Margin="253,67,0,0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" Source="images/steering-wheel.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                         From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

What I'm after is detecting when the user is "dragging" that steering wheel left or right and transforming the image's rotation angle accordingly. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar

you need 2 reference points to calculate the rotation the centre of the steering wheel and the position of the mouse this is done as follows

```
private void Steering_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var control = sender as Ellipse;
        var point = e.GetPosition(control);
        var centre = new Point(control.Width / 2, control.Height / 2);
        var vector = point  - centre
        Steering.Angle = (Math.Atan2(vector.X,vector.Y) * 180 / Math.PI);
        //note default behaviour of Atan2 is Angle 0 = East and Anti Clockwise is a positive angle, 
        //by swapping X and Y north is now 0 angle and clockwise is positive
    }
}
```

then you just need to bind the rotation

```
<Ellipse 
    MouseMove="Steering_MouseMove" >
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Steering.Angle}" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: I applied a slightly different variation on this: 
`                RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform((Math.Atan2(vector.X, vector.Y) * 180 / Math.PI));
                steering.RenderTransform = rotate;`

Otherwise, thanks - that was enough to get me started.